# Link2SD doesn't really move the apps

Tags: link2sd

I have link2sd with granted root permissions and a partitioned SD card, but when I give Create Link to SD on some big app, it creates just few small files there, like 20-30mb, but the big files of the applications which some are more than 1Gb don't get moved to the second partition... is this supposed to be this way?

Comment: Have you selected to move all 3 things? I believe it doesn't move the data (it doesn't move something, that's for sure).

Comment: yes, everything is selected

Comment: anyone please ?

Comment: Maybe the obb files?

Answer (score -1):

the apk file is stored in the internal memory still, it's in the 'data' folder.  I don't think you can do much about that with earlier versions of android but if you find a way then please let me know!

Comment: the best and easiest solution I have found so far is an app from the market called Folder Mount, it moves all the big files of some games, like for example N.O.V.A. has a file which is 1.90gb, to the SD card, without requiring you to partition the sd card or anything. Still it doesn't move the whole app, but it suits me fine for now